# how to update field value to TittleCase in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to change the firstname to Title case.

```
{    
            "firstName" : "GOPAULAKRISHNAN",
            "middleName" : "",
            "lastName" : "venkatasan",
    }
```

I can able to change to lowercase or to uppercase.but cannot able to change to lower case.

Query i used.

```
db.users.find( {}, { 'firstName': 1 } ).forEach(function(doc) {
db.users.update(
   { _id: doc._id},
   { $set : { 'firstName' : doc.firstName.titleCase() } },
   { multi: true }
)
});
```

Getting this error :

```
uncaught exception: TypeError: doc.firstName.titleCase is not a function :
```

I even tried this method:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
        return word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
    }).join(' ');
}

db.users.find().forEach(function(doc){
    db.users.updateOne(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "firstName": titleCase(doc.firstName) } }
    );
});
```

Comment: Your second procedure _"I even tried this method:..."_ works fine. So, what is the issue?

Comment: E  QUERY    [js] TypeError: word[0] is undefined :                                                          
titleCase/<@(shell):3:9                                                                                                  
titleCase@(shell):2:12                                                                                                     
@(shell):4:34

Comment: This is the error i m getting .

Comment: I ran your code (the second version) from `mongo` shell. Both the JavaScript function `titleCase(str)` and the `mongo` shell update method work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `titleCase` function is giving error for empty strings and null values

Just include `falsy` value check before applying any functions like toLowerCase etc in your case.

```js
    function titleCase(str) {
        return str && str.toLowerCase().split(/\s/).map(function(word) {
            return word && word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
        }).join(' ');
    }
    
    console.log(titleCase(undefined));
    
    console.log(titleCase(""));

    console.log(titleCase(null));
    
    console.log(titleCase("NAMAR"));
```

see that **&&** added to check for `empty strings, null, undefined` values